# Changing display on CiviCase search results

Tags: civicase, search, display

Currently, when I search using Find Cases on CiviCase, the results are displayed in 9 columns: Client, Subject, Status, Case Type, My Role, Case Manager, Most Recent, Next Sched., Actions.

We don't involve assigning Civi activities much in our workflow so these fields are pretty much useless to us: **Most Recent, Next Sched.**

I would also like to add a results column that includes the Case Start Date.

How can I make this change?

Answer (score 1):

You've picked a hard one to customize since there's multiple technologies involved on that screen and the results load after the rest of the page but without an easy way to hook into it to change it. You might want to instead go to Reports - Case Reports and use the Case Details report to select your fields and then on the Filters tab choose the criteria.